# How to extract specific files using FIND + TAR command

Tags: find, tar

I would like to know if it is possible to extract a specific file inside `tar` file using find command.

Example:

- Normal situation: find filaname called "file1" and extract

  ```
  tar xvf tarfilename file1
  ```
- My Situation:

  ```
  find . -iname "*tar*" -exec tar -xvf *file1* {} \;
  ```

  I don't know if possible to do.

**Reason:**

My internal prod system is not allowed to run `tar` command.

I know that the best practice is running tar directly, but the hope dies last

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you check http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html before? Since 2005, `star` has a builtin `find`. Or do you rather like `find` to be used to locate tar archives that later are going to be extracted via `tar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't run `tar` directly from the shell, but can run it from a different command, then you can do:

```
env tar xvf file.tar file1
find . -prune -exec tar xvf file.tar file1 ';'
perl -e 'exec @ARGV' tar xvf file.tar file1
```

However, that still runs `tar`, so you would likely still be infringing at least the spirit of the law that forbids you from running `tar`.

Instead of `tar`, you could also run `pax` instead (that's the POSIX command for dealing with archives).

```
pax -r < file.tar file1
```

Comment: I'm able to use env tar to solve my problem

Thank you so much.